# JSX adding attribute with no value with conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So in JSX I know how I can use an conditional on class names etc or where the attribute has a value.

So if I'm doing `class="something"` or `style="something"` etc. The issue I'm having is i'm unsure how I'd do a conditional when adding the `hidden` attribute.

Example;

```
  className={classNames({
    'hidden': true,
    'visible': props.showAll,
  })}
```

This will add a class depending on the value of `showAll`.

But the `hidden` attribute is literally just `<p hidden>this text is hidden</p>`.

How would I go about adding a conditional into my JSX react component that renders an attribute but no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try with:

```
<p hidden={!showAll}>
```

Attribute `hidden` with no value is concidered as `true`, so you can easily pass a boolean value.

Comment: Ahh so `hidden=""` returns true, the same as just adding the `hidden` attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the data is present then show otherwise do not append the p tag on dom.So try this

```
{this.props.showAll && <p>this.props.showAll</p>}
```